# Insert value to div

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor, end-to-end

I have  HTML + Angular looks like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.colDef.name" class="ui-grid-cell ng-scope ui-grid-coluiGrid-15T" ng-class="{ 'ui-grid-row-header-cell': col.isRowHeader }" ui-grid-cell="">
    <div class="ui-grid-cell-contents ng-binding ng-scope ui-grid-cell-focus" tabindex="-1">33</div>
</div>
```

and it looks like:

[image]

And I need to add / change value whihch is between  divs (in this example it's number 33)
How ever i try to sendkey that it's not helping. I double check if my XPATH is correct but still...

```
var pkValue = "11";
element(by.xpath('(/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/form/fieldset[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div)')).sendKeys(pkValue);
```

Is there something I'm missing or if I need to do something else for this?

Comment: Instead of getting the element via XPath, couldn't you use the $index to work out the row and update directly?

Comment: Hi HockeyJ, let me thank you for your answer, unfortunately I already tryed other ways then xpath , I belieave problem is how to touch and edit this value.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice you had Protractor in the tags.

Comment: It's okey :) , still thank you for trying to help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [set an `innerHTML`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21695714/using-javascript-to-set-text-for-a-web-element-selenium-web-driver) using [`executeScript()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.executeScript):

```
var elm = element(by.xpath('(/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/form/fieldset[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div)'));

browser.executeScript("arguments[0].innerHTML = '11';", elm.getWebElement());
```

Also, think about changing the xpath you are using - this one (an absolute one starting from the `html` root element) is very fragile.

Comment: Hi alecxe, 
thank you for your answer,. I usually try to avoid use absolute XPATH but here just to make sure it's correct I copy it from browser. 

Anyway after I try this I'm getting error: RangeError: Maximum call stack 
size exceeded

Any idea?

Comment: @Andurit okay, what protractor and browser and browser version are you using?

Comment: Protractor = newest ( i just download everything from git like 2 weeks back)
Browser: Google Chrome Verze 39.0.2171.71 m

Comment: @Andurit really not sure what is the problem at the moment. Is the site online (so I can test it and reproduce the issue also)? Also, try the same test with firefox please (use 34.0.5 version). Thank you.

Comment: Site is online but with limited access from the world, and I can't do much with that atm :( 
After test on FF i get the same error.

I know it's hard to help if you don't see the site, but any hit which can help?

Comment: @Andurit ok, I understand, please provide the complete traceback of the error that you are currently getting. Thanks.

Comment: Log is too long so unfortunately I can't add it to comment,
so here it is:
http://pastebin.com/UZNqrqJ9

Comment: @Andurit thank you for the traceback - are you sure it is failing on the `executeScript` line? Thanks.

Comment: I like the way you are thinking @alecxe , i was thinking the same way and comment out every other code then this from that 'it()' , atm it looks like:
http://pastebin.com/VNvYfeFx