# How to change the text of a span that acts like a button

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am working on writing automation tests for a custom web application.  I am running into a problem where I can't change the text of a span.  I have tried using driver.execute_script but have had no luck. (It would really help if I knew javascript better)  As far as I know you can't click a span and the list is populated as a list of . What is the best way to change this text?

[image]

Comment: Please replace the image with `html` and let us know what you have tried with

Answer (score 9):

You need to set the [`innerHTML` using `execute_script()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21696573/771848):

```
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].innerHTML = "New value";', element)
```

where `element` should point to your `span` element, could be:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.file-wrapper span.k-dropdown span.k-input')
```