# Selenium(PYTHON) Change An Elements Text

Tags: python, html, selenium, webautomation, webbot

i think the title is pretty self explanatory, i was just wondering how you can use

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("ClassWithText")
```

and change the text inside the class

Comment: check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28863834/how-to-change-the-text-of-a-span-that-acts-like-a-button

Comment: ok so it works, but what if i wanted to add a variable that contains text

Comment: driver.execute_script('arguments[0].innerHTML = "New value" + {variableWithText};', element)

Comment: i know its wrong but something along those lines, cause the java script is confusing me

Comment: did you define element?:

Comment: element= driver.find_element_by_class_name("ClassWithText")