# not able to change name of header even with javascript approach in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

currently blocked with this tricky scenario

please refer to attached screen shot for code

I'm not able to change value of header.

```
<div class="tb-title-container unedited"> 
 <h1 class="tb-headline-inner">Untitled List</h1> 
 <input type="text" maxlength="255" class="tb-title-input chromeless"> <label class="tb-list-options">
 </label> </div>
```

[image]

code generated by Selenium IDE

I tried javascript approach as well to set value of header field , but it's not getting changed. As header name change takes place only with keyboard enter key press.

`driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("label.tb-list-options > svg")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li.rename.blue")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.tb-title-input.chromeless")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.tb-title-input.chromeless")).sendKeys("vikram");`

**java code**

```
WebElement inputField  = getDriver().findElement( By.xpath("//div[@class='tb-title-container']/h1[@class='tb-headline-inner']") );

 ( (JavascriptExecutor)getDriver() ).executeScript("arguments[0].value='VIKRAM'", inputField);
```

Comment: so you need to press ENTER after typing to change that field? Then you're missing something like inputField.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);   I am confused by what the problem is, are you not able to locate that, type a new value or press enter once you have your new input.

Comment: @ingrid.e sendKeys on this field throws error element not visible.  I'm not able to mimic user actions on this input field either with normal selenium methods or with javascript as well.

Comment: what is the type of that field? can you not locate it using classname instead?

Comment: as per solution from Kith below , I could locate and set value programmatically but new valud doesn't reflect in UI.  It only updates in UI , once enter key press is done ( during manual interaction ) , how to update value of this field and then do enter key press ?

Comment: what is the type of that element? that is important

Comment: can you please refer to screen shot attached for more details . It's <h1 class="tb-headline-inner">needs_tobe_changed</h1>

Comment: @vikramvi Please don't just post screenshots of your HTML, attach at least part of it as text so that people who want to help by recreating this themselves (rather than guessing) don't have to type it all out themselves.

Comment: @AndrewRegan  sorry for not pasting code sample earlier , I have updated it in the question. Thanks for helping me to improve question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName('tb-title-container').innerHTML='vikram'");
```

Comment: Hi Kith,  this didn't work as well.  I think the step missing is after assigning value , need to do enter key press to confirm the action.  Also please put vikram in single quotes in above line ;  as above one throws error

Comment: Just found a relative issue. Hope it will help.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21695714/using-javascript-to-set-text-for-a-web-element-selenium-web-driver

Comment: sorry I didn't understand the solution from the link you posted. My understanding with javascript is very limited and still learning tricks in it. can you please paste the code here ?  And below is what I tried WebElement inputField  = getDriver().findElement( By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'tb-title-container')]/h1[@class='tb-headline-inner']") );
    
    ((JavascriptExecutor)getDriver()).executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName('tb-title-container').value='vikram'");
    ((JavascriptExecutor)getDriver()).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", inputField);

Comment: sorry it didn't work. I tried the javascript part in FF console , it does pass in console only but doesn't reflect change in UI. I think after this method , it needs enter action through javascript ?